# PowerShell Tests: Module or Individual Files

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, pester

**Background**

I have a PowerShell module where I am starting to write the tests. Each function is stored in its own file with the same name (e.g. `function MyFunction` is stored in a file called `MyFunction.ps1`). Similarly, the tests are stored in a file called `MyFunction.Tests.ps1`. The structure is as below.

```
Source\
    Public\
        MyFunction.ps1
    Private\
Tests\
    MyFunction.Tests.ps1
```

In order to make the module faster to load, during build, all functions are copied into the `.psm1` file.

**Question**

Should the tests (unit tests with code coverage, integration, regression, etc) be run against the function in the individual `.ps1` files or against the whole `.psm1` file? Any information on the pros and cons of each would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like an opinion-based question to me. Usually, storing each function in its own file would leave you with dot-sourcing lots of files, whereas combining them into one single file or module would make loading a lot faster. Modules usually also combine functionality for a specific purpose; could contain helper functions for building forms, dealing with databases etc.

Comment: Agree with @Theo, it starts already with the question whether it is a good idea to [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) your scripts in a module. See: [`#18740` Best practice: import functions in a module](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18740) as it introduces a similar scoping pitfall as with `Invoke-Expression`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> during build, all functions are copied into the `.psm1` file.

Generally speaking, you should always test the code that is *actually used at runtime*, which means you should test against the `.psm1` file.

This guards against hiding the following potential problems, for instance:

- Subtle behavioral differences between code directly placed in a scope and loaded from an external script via dot-sourcing.

  - Similarly, if were to test your `.ps1` files *in isolation* (if even feasible), you could miss potential (unwanted) interaction between the code in the individual files when placed in a single `.psm1` file; also, `.psm1` files behave differently than `.ps1` files.
- Flaws in the build script that creates the single `.psm1` file.

Comment: I retracted my close vote because as the my comment in the question implies, you should indeed always retest the whole module if you make changes to any dot-sourced function script.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0. I was leaning towards this for the reasons you highlighted, but glad to have someone else confirm it.