# What is the purpose of nested modules?

Tags: powershell

I'm currently learning about & building my 1st module, which would be shared between our team and/or contain common functions for our scripts, and I see "nested modules" mentioned a bit, but I don't understand what benefits this provides?

Currently I've setup my module like this, with each function in a separate `.ps1` file

```
- MyModule\   
    - Private\
        - SecretFunction.ps1    
    - Public\
        - AD Stuff\
            - Get-ADUser.ps1    
            - Get-ADGroup.ps1    
        - O365 Stuff\
            - Get-O365User.ps1
    - MyModule.psd1    
    - MyModule.psm1
```

And in my `.psd1` file I define the functions to export

`FunctionsToExport = @('Get-ADUser', 'Get-ADGroup', 'Get-O365User')`

Where would I use nested modules?

Comment: Primarily it's these things: Encapsulation, Reusability, Flexibility, and Performance. Similar to what other OOP languages have used for decades for reference libraries, DLL sharing, etc. [Understanding and Building PowerShell Modules](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-modules/)

Comment: For one thing, (embedded) modules have their own scope, therefore there is less change that an embedded script (accidentally) interferes with it. See also: [PowerShell Tests: Module or Individual Files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75110854/1701026).

Comment: @iRon Thanks, I spent some time to learn more about the scopes. In response to your comment, doesn't each function already run in their own scope? Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: The embedded functions you define in your `.ps1` scripts have their own scope but if you dot-source your scripts, they are loaded in the current scope and therefore share information as variables. As an example, if I define a `Set-StrictMode` in the (root) of one of the dot-sourced scripts, I am setting that for *all* the dot-sourced scripts in the module. If one of the other scripts is not compliant with that script mode level, it might suddenly produce errors.